# Convert a date with GMT to a human readable time zone in an angular app using TS or JS

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I have a date value returned from an api call.  This date includes a value like GMT-7.  How best to turn that into a human readable time zone like 'PST' or 'Pacific Standard Time' so final string will be December 31, 2021 at 4:00:00 PM (PST)  and not GMT-7

The GMT/UTC minus 7 hours offset is used in the Pacific Time Zone during Daylight Saving Time (DST) period and in the Mountain Time Zone during the Standard Time period, when no DST is applied.

Moment.js is not an option because of it's file size and deprecation.

Ok further clarification from my product owner: the time can be returned reflecting the time in the users time zone.  So if it is 7pm EST time in the original date and user is in Pacific Time PST they will see 3pm PST to reflect same time according to their zone.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/ You can try using the recommendation libraries listed there.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use new Date().toLocaleString(......) function.

Comment: The value for the *timeZone* option must be an IANA representative location such as America/Los_Angeles. Also, the "short" option for *timeZoneName* may produce an abbreviation or a value like GMT-0700 depending on the language used, host default language and implementation support. In short, it's not guaranteed to be an abbreviation of the civil timezone name.

Comment: actually this idea did work for my use case with a slight variation.  var dat = new Date("2021-12-18T23:59:00-5:00")    dat.toLocaleString('en-US', {hour12: true, timeZoneName: 'short', month: 'long', day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' })  @The KNVB if you can update your code to not include timeZone as that's only known to the user and the options i listed I will mark this as an accepted answer (for USA at least)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard for timezone names or abbreviations, and sometimes with either *timeZoneName* short or long the *format** methods will return something like GMT+07:00 or UTC+07:00 depending on the browser default language, even if "en" or "en-US" or whatever is specified.

However, you can use [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) with [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) and `timeZoneName:'long'` then abbreviate it yourself where the *timeZoneName* value doesn't contain numbers.

This won't fix cases where the implementation doesn't have a name for the timezone, but for more common timezones like those in Europe and the US with language "en" it should be OK, e.g.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  let {year, month, day, hour, minute, second, timeZoneName} = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
    timeZoneName:'long'
  }).formatToParts(date).reduce((acc, part) => {
    acc[part.type] = part.value;
    return acc;
  }, Object.create(null));
  
  // If timezone doesn't contain numbers, abbreviate
  // Otherwise, return the name as given by formatToParts
  let tz = /\d/.test(timeZoneName)? timeZoneName : timeZoneName.replace(/[^A-Z]/g,'');
  return `${month} ${day}, ${year} ${hour}:${minute}:${second} ${tz}`
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(2021,0,1)));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(2021,5,1)));
```

Comment: hi robg this appears to be hard coding 'America/Los_Angeles' but I don't know what the time zone is until the date is returned it could be any time zone in the USA.  I just know the GMT number

Comment: @JesseBoyd—you can't reliably determine the civil timezone name just from the offset as a particular offset applies to multiple zones, e.g. [UTC +10](https://24timezones.com/time-zone/utc+10) might be AEST, CHST, CHUT, DDUT, PGT or VLAT. Add to that the non–standarisation of names. If you don't want the timezone hard coded, then just remove it from the options.

Answer (score -1):

let date =  api date

new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()))

converts to gmt 00:00

Comment: The OP wants the timestamp to be local to a specific location, not UTC, and wants the offset as an abbreviation of the civil name, not the numeric offset from GMT/UTC.